# PHP array_merge: argument not an array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'm getting some weird behaviour in PHP that I just can't understand.

```
    $count=0;
    $temp=array(); //this is definitely a new variable, not that it should matter
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        if ($arr->bbcode != $previous_bb) {
            $previous_bb=$arr->bbcode; 
            //stuff
            $temp=array_merge($temp,$arr);
         }
     //stuff
    }
```

I've tried to simplify the code a little and just keep what's essential. $array is a 2-D array (so each $arr has some attributes like the bbcode that you see). It complains that argument 1, i.e. $temp, is not an array. Typecasting it to array gives bogus results. Of course, this is within other code, which I can give more details of if needed, but any ideas? I've used the exact same sort of code and syntax in other places and it doesn't complain...

EDIT: Feel free to downvote liberally, had a memory lapse about what I had been working with and how I'd been doing things. Never had to ask a programming question before (in several years), thanks a ton guys, you are immensely fast!

Comment: Is the title of the question the actual error given?

Comment: If the error message says it's not an array, it's not an array.  What happens when you vardump or gettype()?

Comment: I retract that, it's always an array (spelling error)

Comment: The exact error: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array (surely it doesn't start counting from 0 does it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are trying to merge an object ($arr) with an array ($temp). PHP should complain that $arr is not an array. See the example code below:

   ```
   php > $obj = new StdClass();
   php > $obj->property = "value";
   php > $arr = [];
   php > array_merge($arr, $obj);

   Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in php shell code on line 1

   Call Stack:
      33.2510     230352   1. {main}() php shell code:0
      33.2510     230960   2. array_merge() php shell code:1
   ```
2. Typecasting in php is always a bit tricky, if you do so check [the type juggling documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php) to see what happens when.
3. Before trying to optimize your code, what do you want to achieve? A new list which is cleaned of duplicate bb codes?

Comment: For some reason it was complaining about the wrong argument, which I won't try to figure out why, and was part of the source of my confusion. Thanks for the good answer :) As for 3, no, and this is the most efficient way of doing what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your two arguments.

- `$temp` is initialised as `array()`, and repeatedly assigned to the return value of `array_merge` which (unless things go wrong) is always an array.
- `$arr`. Well, it's in the name, right? That's about as reliable as `$two = 3;`. You are accessing `$arr->bbcode` so it is clearly an object and not an array.

Did you mean `$temp[] = $arr;`?

Comment: True that, and what I've done isn't exactly exemplary programming. Why has it worked elsewhere then (In exactly the same sort of situation)? Edit: OK, I see what I did differently.